# how to implement playing programme in Android IPTV like Perfect player

Tags: android, exoplayer, iptv

I had implement playing timeshift streams according to xtreme codes timeshift api.
but I wanna play all programmes of channel like perfect player.

http://ip:port/streaming/timeshift.php?username=X&password=X&stream=X&start=2016-03-19:16-00&duration=120

if you are expert in IPTV expert, I would like to get help from you.

Comment: Provide some code what have you tried so far ?

Comment: String urlToString = "http://ip:port/streaming/timeshift.php?username=X&password=X&stream=X&start=2016-03-19:16-00&duration=120";

 videoPlayer.destroy();
                initExoPlayer(_instance.getView());
                videoPlayer.playUrl(urlToStream, "mp4", true);